# Convert integer to record

Tags: ada

I get an 16 Bit integer from C. This integer consists of 16 flags.

How can I convert this integer in a record of 16 booleans?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question about Ada or C?

Comment: This question is about ada. I get an short Integer from C passed to ada. Now i use Unchecked_Conversion to convert short integer to record.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; this should help you get better answers.

Comment: I've removed the C tag, since it is confusing some people into giving answers in C, which you don't want.

Answer (score 4):

```
type Flags is record
   Flag1 : Boolean;
   Flag2 : Boolean;
   - ...
   Flag15 : Boolean;
end record;

for Flags use record
   Flag1  at 0 range 0 .. 0;
   Flag2  at 0 range 1 .. 1;
   -- ...
   Flag15 at 0 range 15 .. 15;
 end record;
 for Flags'Size use 16;

 -- This is vital, because normally, records are passed by-reference in Ada.
 -- However, as we use this type with C, it has to be passed by value.
 -- C_Pass_By_Copy was introduced in GNAT and is part of the language since Ada 2005.
 pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy, Flags);
```

You can use this type directly in the declaration of the imported C function instad of the C integer type.

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply perform 16 right bit shifts and bitwise AND the result with 1 to determine whether or not a bit/flag is set. Here's an example (I'm hoping this isn't homework):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef unsigned char BOOL;

int main(void)
{
   unsigned i;
   uint16_t flags = 0x6E8B; /* 0b0110111010001011 */
   BOOL arr[16];

   for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      arr[i] = (flags >> i) & 1;
      printf("flag %u: %u\n", i+1, arr[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

`arr[0]` will contain the least significant bit, and `arr[15]` the most significant.

Output:

```
flag 1: 1
flag 2: 1
flag 3: 0
flag 4: 1
flag 5: 0
flag 6: 0
flag 7: 0
flag 8: 1
flag 9: 0
flag 10: 1
flag 11: 1
flag 12: 1
flag 13: 0
flag 14: 1
flag 15: 1
flag 16: 0
```

Comment: @tim-oleksii: What exactly would you use `memcpy` for?

Comment: thx but i need it for ada. Sorry for that mistake. It was my first post here.

Answer (score 3):

In Ada, you can usually declare an imported function to take parameters or return values of the type you want, rather than a C-equivalent type which you then have to convert.

So, here, you want

```
type Flags is array (0 .. 15) of Boolean;
for Flags'Component_Size use 1;
for Flags'Size use 16;
pragma Convention (C, Flags);
```

and you can declare your function as

```
function Get_Flags return Flags;
pragma Import (C, Get_Flags, “get_flags");
```

which with

```
unsigned short get_flags(void) {
  return 0x6e8b;
}
```

and a simple harness gave me

```
flag 0 is TRUE
flag 1 is TRUE
flag 2 is FALSE
flag 3 is TRUE
flag 4 is FALSE
flag 5 is FALSE
flag 6 is FALSE
flag 7 is TRUE
flag 8 is FALSE
flag 9 is TRUE
flag 10 is TRUE
flag 11 is TRUE
flag 12 is FALSE
flag 13 is TRUE
flag 14 is TRUE
flag 15 is FALSE
```

As Bo Persson noted, this is fine so long as your code only needs to run on a little-endian machine. If you want it to run on a SPARC or a Powerbook, it’s probably best to use trashgod’s suggestion;

```
subtype Flags is Interfaces.C.unsigned_short;
use type Flags;

function Get_Flags return Flags;
pragma Import (C, Get_Flags, "get_flags");
```

and then, probably, name your flag bits (with something more meaningful!)

```
Flag_3 : constant Flags := 2#0000_0000_0000_1000#;
```

or (probably more like the C)

```
Flag_4 : constant Flags := 2 ** 4;
```

and then check

```
(Get_Flags and Flag_3) /= 0
```

Comment: @flyx pointed out that Ada passes records to C by reference unless you tell it `pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy)`. Ada also [passes arrays to C by reference](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html#p70), but you can’t apply `C_Pass_By_Copy` to arrays, which is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

In Ada, a [*modular type*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html) allows logical operations to access a value as a bit set. Introduced in Ada 95, an overview may be found in the [*Ada 95 Rationale, §3.3.2 Modular Types*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-3.html#3-2). Depending on implementation, the pre-defined type [`Interfaces.C.unsigned_short`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3.html) my be a convenient choice for obtaining the value from C.

Comment: +1. Even though this isn't what he asked for, its likely what he needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use overlaying to achieve the desired result; let's assume that these booleans are all meaningful and strictly boolean (i.e. nothing that's an enumeration).

First you need to define your record; I'm going to be using a single Nybble to illustrate, but the principle is applicable. The Nybble is the old DOS attributes: reading (visibility-wise; should be Is_Hidden, in retrospect), write, archive, and system.

```
Type Nyble_Data is mod 2**4;
For Nyble_Data'Size use 4;

Type Data_Record is record
    Can_Read, Can_Write, Is_Archived, Is_System : Boolean:= False;
end record;

-- Ensure 4 bits used.
pragma Pack (Data_Record);
For Data_Record'Size use 4;

-- Specify Layout.
For Data_Record use
    record
        Can_Read    at 0 range 0..0;
        Can_Write   at 0 range 1..1;
        Is_Archived at 0 range 2..2;
        Is_System   at 0 range 3..3;
    end record;

-- This is where the magic occurs.
Function Convert( Data : In Nyble_Data ) Return Data_Record is
    Result : Data_Record;
    For Result'Address use Data'Address;
    Pragma Import( Convention => Ada, Entity => Result );
    Pragma Inline( Convert );
begin
    Return Result;
end Convert;

-- Test variables.
Input   : Nyble_Data:= 5;
Output  : Data_Record:= Convert(Input);

-- Display the record.
Procedure Put( Data : In Data_Record ) is
    Use Ada.Text_IO;
begin
    Put_Line( "Read:   "    & ASCII.HT & Boolean'Image(Data.Can_Read) );
    Put_Line( "Write:  "    & ASCII.HT & Boolean'Image(Data.Can_Write) );
    Put_Line( "Archive:"    & ASCII.HT & Boolean'Image(Data.Is_Archived) );
    Put_Line( "System: "    & ASCII.HT & Boolean'Image(Data.Is_System) );
end Put;
```

Comment: [Recently on comp.lang.ada](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/msg/237cb72df383266a) Randy Brukhardt wrote "it's just like overlaying objects using address clauses -- it might work, but its still wrong and there is no guarentee that a newer compiler version will not break such things.” `Unchecked_Conversion` is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union containing a short int (or a int_16) and a bit field:

```
union UMyFlags {
    short n;
    struct {
        flag_1 : 1;
        flag_2 : 1;
        // other flags ...
    } flags;
};
```

However, because of byte ordering, your code will not be portable on every platform.

Comment: Not only byte ordering differs, the order of the bit fields in the struct is also implementation dependent.